# A circularly polarized EM wave is perfectly absorbed by any interface?

Tags: wave, theory, optics, em

According to the [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations), the effective reflectivity of an arbitrarily polarized electromagnetic wave is given as:

$$
\Gamma = \frac{\Gamma_p + \Gamma_s}{2} ,
$$

where \$\Gamma_p\$ and \$\Gamma_s\$ are the reflectivities for p and s polarization, respectively.

I assume the common scenario of an electromagnetic wave traveling through empty space (\$n_1=1; \epsilon_1=\epsilon_0, \mu_1=\mu_0\$) hitting a non-magnetic surface (\$\mu_2=\mu_0\$) with dielectric \$\epsilon_2=\epsilon_0 \epsilon_2'\$ (\$n_2=\sqrt{\epsilon_2'}\$) at a straight angle.

If I plug these into the [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) with an angle of incidence \$\theta_i=0\$, I obtain:

$$
\Gamma_p = \frac{\epsilon_2'-\sqrt{\epsilon_2'}}{\epsilon_2'+\sqrt{\epsilon_2'}} , \\
\Gamma_s = \frac{1-\sqrt{\epsilon_2'}}{1+\sqrt{\epsilon_2'}} .
$$

Then it is easy to see that \$\Gamma=(\Gamma_p+\Gamma_s)/2=0\$ ! This suggests that any circularly polarized wave hitting a surface at a perpendicular angle would be perfectly aborbed. That must be nonsense.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: THis is easy to answer: what do the p and s in your polarization names stand for?

Comment: senkrecht und parallel ;-) How does this answer? (I see how the wave-fronts are reaching the surface for both cases: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnelsche_Formeln#/media/Datei:Polarisation_s.png and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnelsche_Formeln#/media/Datei:Polarisation_p.png)

Comment: senkrcht means "normal to the surface"; and your wave is hitting the surface in a straight angle, and since there's no longitudinal field components in electromagnetic waves in free space...

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand. Both, \$\Gamma_p \neq 0\$ and \$\Gamma_s \neq 0\$! For example, for \$\epsilon_2'=9\$, \$\Gamma_p = 0.5\$ and \$\Gamma_s = -0.5\$. This makes sense. In both cases things are reflected. My question is why does in the **circularly polarized** case nothing seem to be reflected?

Comment: maybe I'm misinterpreting what "in a straight angle" means

Comment: It really just means \$\theta_i=0\$ (EM wave travels perpendicular towards the surface): You stand in front of a wall and send an RF wave directly at the wall. You would expect some parts of the signal to always be reflected back towards you, right? (of course, for \$\epsilon_2 > 1\$). My question is why this seemingly doesn't happen when the wave is circularly polarized.

In an optical sense, it would mean that the wall would need to appear black because it would not reflect (circularly) polarized light.

Comment: if your wave incides perpendicularly, then \$\Gamma_S=0\$; there's no field component in the direction of propagation of the wave.